# The method of construct a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, wav

I used the function "wavread()" to load a .wav file into memory,and store the signals in column vector y,then I get a row vector yRow(=y').

Then I define a matrix myframe=zeros(frameNum,frameLen);

what I want to do is fill myframe by the items of yRow:

```
index=1;
myframe(1,:)=yRow(index:index+frameLen-1)

for i=2:frameNum-1
   myframe(i,:)=yRow(index*frameStep:index*frameStep+frameLen-1)
   index=index+1
end

myframe(frameNum,1:sigLen-frameNum*frameStep+1)=yRow(frameNum*frameStep:sigLen)
```

But it takes a very long time to fill "myframe",I think there must be something wrong,please help me to find out the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding semicolon at the end of each sentence can stop outputing informations in command window.The program can run in back end quickly.
SO,this is the matter of ";".

Answer (score 0):

use **reshape** function in matlab as:

```
myframe=reshape(y,frameNum,frameLen);
```